# Where can I purchase SharePoint and how much does it cost?

Tags: licensing

I want to make a web site and I heard about SharePoint. I have little bit of knowledge about SharePoint but I want to know how to make web sites in it. It is very vast software.

From where I can purchase this software and how much will it cost to buy this software?

Answer (score 10):

If you're building a simple website, do NOT use SharePoint.

The reason being, SharePoint is a vast, complex platform with many features aimed at collaboration. versioning and distribution of content, as well as managing content workflow, and requires a significant, performant and expensive infrastructure to be able to run the simplest of environments.

Unless you have a very large team of authors whose work requires approval, and publishing across many websites in many languages in your company, I strongly suggest against using SharePoint to publish a website.

To answer your query about pricing and availability - SharePoint Foundation 2010 is available from the Microsoft Website, and the licensing comes with your Windows Server licences.

SharePoint Server 2010 has a separate licensing model and you will need one CAL per user who will access this, or an Internet Connector licence which can be very, very costly.

In addition to the licensing costs, you will need staff and time to maintain the hardware infrastructure on which your SharePoint environment runs, as well as maintenance of the software environment itself, and development/consultancy/training for installing, configuring and building the environment to your specifications.

Answer (score 4):

If you decide to go with SharePoint and your site does not need to access other applications/data on your network, then I would suggest going with a hosted solution.  There are multiple companies that provide SharePoint hosting.  One that I've used a few times is [FPWEB](http://www.fpweb.net).  They have a free trial available so it would be worth taking SharePoint for a spin to see if it is right for you.  With a hosted account, you do not need to worry about the user licenses -- you just pay a flat monthly fee.

Answer (score 0):

When choosing a technology to build own website, you have to specify firstly the following points:

- The nature of your Website.
- your business Model.
- your financial and technical capabilities.